# Get all the checked rows in a kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a Kendo grid with a checkbox as a column along with other columns. I want to get all the rows where the checkbox is checked.

Please give me some idea.

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle and add jQuery tag also

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the multi select feature of Kendo ui Grid

```
    var checkDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: checks
    });

    $("#CheckGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: checkDataSource,
        change: CheckGridOnChange,
        selectable:"multiple",
        ...
     });


    function CheckGridOnChange() {
        var data = checkDataSource.view(),
            selected = $.map(this.select(), function(item) {
                return data[$(item).index()].CheckId;//CheckId is my unqiue id for my data, yours would probably be different
        });
        var ids = selected.join(",");
     }
```

Ref url: [Kendo ui grid Events](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/events.html) Just hold control and select multiple rows